# Get information about Event Log settings

Tags: powershell, event-log

In powershell there are a number of commands to manipulate and view the event log. I can set the size/settings with `Limit-EventLog`. However I can not find a way to get the current settings about the log. I want to know what the maximum size the log is allowed to grow to is set as.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `get-winevent`

```
get-winevent -ListLog Application | fl *
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I couldn't find that!